# Issue with 1L format

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

When doing this:

```
np.array(data.ix[:,i])).shape
```

I get `(number,)` on a machine with Python 3, but on a Python 2 doing the same thing I get the long format `(numberL,)`. How can I make python 2 use the standard numeric type instead of the long type?

Comment: That depends entirely on the numbers you're storing ... Are they bigger than `sys.maxint`?

Answer (score 0):

If the data don't fit into an `int`, it automatically uses `long` in Python 2. In Py3, this distinction has gone.

Probabl your result (or one of the intermediate results) doesn't fit in an `int`, or one of the functions involved generally uses `long`.

It shouldn't bother you; when printing or converting to a string, the result should be the same.